# How to get sum and separate the total per Id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

> This is my query in my controller

```
  public function show($id)
    {
        $Days = DB::table('payroll_monthly_attn_project')->where('payroll_monthly_id',$id)->where('assign','PAINTING')
        ->select('payroll_monthly_attn_project.wrk_id','payroll_monthly_attn_project.project_code','payroll_monthly_attn_project.assign','payroll_monthly_attn_project.days');

        $Monthly_details = DB::table('payroll_monthly_payable_details')->where('payroll_monthly_payable_details.payroll_monthly_id', $id)
                           ->select('payroll_monthly_payable_details.daily_rate','payroll_monthly_payable_details.late','payroll_monthly_payable_details.ut','payroll_monthly_payable_details.absent','days.*')
                           ->leftjoinSub($Days,'days',function($join){
                            $join->on('payroll_monthly_payable_details.wrk_id','=','days.wrk_id');    

                           })
                        ->get();
   
        return $Monthly_details;
    }
```

> Result of my query... I want to get total of separate `project_code`

```
0: {daily_rate: 8.63, late: 0, ut: 0, absent: 0, wrk_id: 3, project_code: "CMUN", assign: "PAINTING",…}
absent: 0
assign: "PAINTING"
daily_rate: 8.63
days: 13
late: 0
project_code: "CMUN"
ut: 0
wrk_id: 3
1: {daily_rate: 575.08, late: 0, ut: 0, absent: 0, wrk_id: 2, project_code: "N2", assign: "PAINTING",…}
absent: 0
assign: "PAINTING"
daily_rate: 575.08
days: 7
late: 0
project_code: "N2"
ut: 0
wrk_id: 2
2: {daily_rate: 57.51, late: 0, ut: 0, absent: 0, wrk_id: 4, project_code: "N2", assign: "PAINTING",…}
absent: 0
assign: "PAINTING"
daily_rate: 57.51
days: 13
late: 0
project_code: "N2"
ut: 0
wrk_id: 4
```

> Also I tried this but it only get the sum of all

```
  public function show($id)
    {
 
        $Days = DB::table('payroll_monthly_attn_project')->where('payroll_monthly_id',$id)->where('assign','PAINTING')
        ->select('payroll_monthly_attn_project.wrk_id','payroll_monthly_attn_project.project_code','payroll_monthly_attn_project.assign','payroll_monthly_attn_project.days');

        $Monthly_details = DB::table('payroll_monthly_payable_details')->where('payroll_monthly_payable_details.payroll_monthly_id', $id)
                           ->select('payroll_monthly_payable_details.daily_rate','payroll_monthly_payable_details.late','payroll_monthly_payable_details.ut','payroll_monthly_payable_details.absent','days.*')
                           ->leftjoinSub($Days,'days',function($join){
                            $join->on('payroll_monthly_payable_details.wrk_id','=','days.wrk_id');    

                           })
                        ->get();

        $fetch = [];
        $grandTotal = 0;
        foreach($Monthly_details as $key){

            $grandTotal += ($key->daily_rate * $key->days) - $key->absent - $key->late - $key->ut;

        }
        $fetch['grandTotal'] = $grandTotal;

        return $fetch;
    }
```

> Result of my query..

```
{grandTotal: 4885.38}
grandTotal: 4885.38
```

Result I want to achieve..

```
"CMUN"{project_code:"CMUN"
total:112.19},
"N2"{project_code:"N2"
total:4773.19}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the query.
Just change the foreach loop code.

```
foreach($Monthly_details as $key){
    if(empty($fetch[$key->project_code])){
        $fetch[$key->project_code]['total'] = 0;
    }
    $fetch[$key->project_code]['total'] += ($key->daily_rate * $key->days) - $key->absent - $key->late - $key->ut;
}
return $fetch;
```

// The Section which calls the function show().

```
$results = work($id);
foreach($results as $projectCode => $total){
   echo $projectCode." total cost is: ".$total;
}
```

Comment: Great !! But how can I dispay value that the total is belong to what project?. I want to display Project_code together with total amount

Comment: For that you need to write a foreach loop and access the projectCode as key of the result and the total as the value from the place where you are calling the work() function.
Please check my updated answer.

Comment: where I can put that code? I'm sorry I'm just begginer hope u understand me :(

Comment: I got it .. in my vue I use `v-for="(fetch,index) in paintdata"` and it dispay the index of the object

Comment: Yes based on the vue js you have to write it. Please upvote the answer, If it helped you.